# can't get my sip client to connect to asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Good day people, I am new to asterisk, I run it on Ubuntu 11 and I am using Asterisk 1.8.3.2. I have configured my sip and extensions configrations, but I cant get my sip client from my android phone to work on it, I keep getting no matching peers error.

Below are my configuration

sip.conf

```
[general]
context=unauthenticated
allowguest=no
srvlookup=yes
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
tcpenable=no

[office-phone](!)
type=friend
context=LocalSets
host=dynamic
nat=yes
secret=s3CuR#p@s5
dtmfmode=auto
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw

[0000FFFF0001](office-phone)
[0000FFFF0002](office-phone)
```

extensions.conf

```
[LocalSets]
exten => 5010,1,Dial(SIP/5010) 
exten => 5020,1,Dial(SIP/5020)
```

What am I missing?
I have reloaded both files and restarted my asterisk server.

Thank you.

Comment: Enable verbose mode and have the client connect to asterisk, that may give you a better idea of what's going on. Open asterisk cli and write core set verbose 3

Answer (score 1):

try removing the '@' from your password, can be a parsing glitch ...

Answer (score 0):

set `nat=no` , because you have to change configurations if Asterisk is running behind a NAT.

sources:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions
http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=76981

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue in your softphone' settings, not in Asterisk.

Make sure you have specified the right account settings and the right server settings on your phone device.  And make sure the port is unblocked in linux.